# Check condition on several if statements for delete in trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, triggers, sql-delete

I have this trigger that checks that if no data is stored in the childtable 'Spacemixes' which relates to a Workspace (Areanr,Spacenr), a delete of a Workspace is allowed in the table 'Workspaces'. Otherwise the trigger fires to prevent a delete. But if I want to make this check for several childtables, and not only 'Spacemixes' - how is that done?

Current trigger code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_DeleteWorkspace ON Workspaces
FOR DELETE AS
BEGIN

--Check if data is in childtable 'Spacemixes':
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Spacemixes s WHERE
(s.areanr <> (select d.areanr from deleted d))
AND
(s.spacenr <> (select d.spacenr from deleted d))
)
--If not, delete a workpace:
BEGIN
delete from Workspaces
where (areanr = (Select d.areanr FROM deleted d))
and
(spacenr = (select d.spacenr from deleted d))
END

--If there's data in childtable, print out error msg and do a rollback
ELSE
Begin
 raiserror('Cannot delete a workspace when data is stored in child tables!', 16, 1)
 rollback transaction
End

END
```

Sample data:

```
--Parent table
CREATE TABLE Workspaces (
Areanr CHAR(2)
CONSTRAINT ck_a_areanr REFERENCES areanr(areanr)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
Spacenr INT
CONSTRAINT ck_spacenr CHECK (spacenr > 0 AND spacenr < 1001),
Area DECIMAL(2,1)
CONSTRAINT ck_area CHECK (area > 0),
CONSTRAINT ck_workspaces PRIMARY KEY (areanr, spacenr)
)

--Example of a childtable:
CREATE TABLE Spacemixes (
Areanr CHAR(2),
Spacenr INT,
Woodcode CHAR(1)
CONSTRAINT ck_y_spacemixes REFERENCES Woodtypes(Code),
Percentage INT
CONSTRAINT ck_percentage CHECK (percentage >= 0 AND percentage < 11),
CONSTRAINT fk_spacemixes FOREIGN KEY (Areanr, Spacenr) REFERENCES Workspaces(Areanr, Spacenr)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT ck_spacemixes PRIMARY KEY (Areanr, Spacenr, Woodcode)
)
```

DESIRED RESULT:

Let's say I'm trying to delete a Workspace (Areanr and Spacenr is the PK in Workspaces):

```
DELETE Workspaces WHERE Areanr=1 AND Spacenr=2
```

If there is a child table using the (Areanr=1 and Spacenr=2), the delete should NOT be allowed. Otherwise it should.

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger as coded will not handle multi-row deletes.  Remember that a trigger fires once per statement rather than once per row so the code should assume the deleted table may contain multiple rows.

The technique below uses a join rather than scalar subqueries to identify affected rows.  Just add EXISTS subqueries for your other child tables.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Workspaces(
      areanr int
    , spacenr int
    , CONSTRAINT PK_Workspaces PRIMARY KEY(areanr, spacenr)
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Spacemixes(
      areanr int
    , spacenr int
    , CONSTRAINT PK_Spacemixes PRIMARY KEY(areanr, spacenr)
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.SomeOtherTable(
      areanr int
    , spacenr int
    , CONSTRAINT PK_SomeOtherTable PRIMARY KEY(areanr, spacenr)
);

INSERT INTO dbo.Workspaces VALUES(1,1)
INSERT INTO dbo.Workspaces VALUES(2,2)
INSERT INTO dbo.Workspaces VALUES(3,3)
INSERT INTO dbo.Workspaces VALUES(4,4)

INSERT INTO dbo.Spacemixes VALUES(1,1)
INSERT INTO dbo.SomeOtherTable VALUES(1,1)

INSERT INTO dbo.Spacemixes VALUES(2,2)
INSERT INTO dbo.SomeOtherTable VALUES(3,3)
GO

CREATE TRIGGER trg_DeleteWorkspace ON dbo.Workspaces
    FOR DELETE
AS
    --Check if data is in childtable 'Spacemixes':
    IF EXISTS ( SELECT  *
                    FROM    Spacemixes s
                            JOIN deleted d ON d.areanr = s.areanr
                                              AND d.spacenr = s.spacenr )
        OR EXISTS ( SELECT *
                         FROM   SomeOtherTable s
                                JOIN deleted d ON d.areanr = s.areanr
                                                  AND d.spacenr = s.spacenr  )
        BEGIN
            RAISERROR('Cannot delete a workspace when data is stored in child tables!', 16, 1);
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        END;
GO

--this fails due to rows in both Spacemixes and SomeOtherTable
DELETE FROM dbo.WorkSpaces
WHERE areanr = 1;
GO

--this fails due to row in Spacemixes
DELETE FROM dbo.WorkSpaces
WHERE areanr = 2;
GO

--this fails due to row in SomeOtherTable
DELETE FROM dbo.WorkSpaces
WHERE areanr = 3;
GO

--this succeeds
DELETE FROM dbo.WorkSpaces
WHERE areanr = 4;
GO
```

Comment: I tried your trigger, but it doesn't work. I can delete a workspace regardless if data is stored in "childtable1" or "childtable2", which should not be allowed. It should only be allowed if no data is stored in child tables. See my edited post on desired result.

Comment: @equinna, I had the same column name (areanr) instead of spacenr in the subqueries and delete statement.  Please try with the updated the SQL.

Comment: I saw that the column names were the same and corrected the column names when I tried it the first time, but it still didn't work though. :-(

Comment: @equinna, I changed NOT EXISTS to EXISTS and removed the extraneous DELETE (since this is an after trigger).  I also added DDL and sample data.

Comment: I literally copied and pasted your code now, and tried to delete a workspace (1, 1) which worked because Spacemixes didn't use it - so far so good. Then I tried to delete a workspace (3, 2) which were in use in Spacemixes, and I could delete the workspace. So when I try it in my DBMS (Sql-server 2014) your trigger doesn't work.

Comment: @equinna, there is no workspace(3,2) in the sample data I provided.  My understanding is that the relationship between these tables is on both areanr and spacenr but I may be misunderstanding.  Can you please post CREATE TABLE and sample data?

Comment: No, but there is a workspace(3,2) in my tables. And when I tested the trigger applied on my tables, and values in them, it didn't work. But now I've edited my post with sample data.

Comment: The reason is the referencing `ON DELETE CASCASDE` constraint.  This will delete the rows from Spacemixes before the trigger fires.  You need to specify NO ACTION for the foreign key constraint if you want to enforce the RI in triggers.